# How to set an invalidHandler for all forms?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have several form that all share the same invalid handler, is there a way to set it as the standard invalidHandler for all the forms of the website?

Thank you

Comment: Please explain more about what you're trying to accomplish and show a bit of relevant code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ 
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
           // your custom function
        },
        // any other options to set as default
    });

});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/setDefaults#defaults

Comment: Yes that was it couldn't find the documentation anywhere, thank you.